# Is there any custom command indicator

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator

Basically I would like to have an indicator that will run and display the output of a custom command (like `uptime`) or script (self-written), just like Xubuntu have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `indicator-sysmonitor`.
You can install it using this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexeftimie/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
```

It displays memory and CPU by default, but you can use the command or script you want.

See that script for example: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-display-network-upload-download.html